# How to make mount points inaccesible for any user or process in Ubuntu, when no filesystem is using it?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, fstab, vuze

I have noticed that my mountpoints in `/media` often acquire underscores, double or triple at time, when I use Vuze which is configured to save the files on a mountpoint directory in `/media`.

This is *very* annoying as it often spoils the downloads and furthermore, it creates versions of files that are confusing I have to spend time resolving and deleting.

Is there any way to **forbid access to a mountpoint**, when there is no file system from `/etc/fstab` mounted on it?

Answer (score 0):

For filesystems with fixed paths like `/home`, I often `chmod 000` the underlying directory so that I can't accidentally put things there when the filesystem isn't mounted.  But the mountpoints in `/media` are created and removed dynamically (by udev, I think).  You shouldn't have leftover directories in there with nothing mounted on them; if you do, that's the real problem you should be trying to solve.  Mountpoints in `/media` are supposed to be automatically deleted when the filesystem is unmounted.